# Missing 300GB harddisk, how to recover it?

Tags: macos, catalina, disk-utility, partition, recovery

I had a bootcamp partion which I removed, how can I recover the 300 GB disk space it used?

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         120.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data DAVE.DATA               71.0 GB    disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +120.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     89.0 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 85.6 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                528.9 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.3 GB    disk1s5

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +184.6 MB   disk2
   1:                  Apple_HFS CleanMyMac X            184.5 MB   disk2s1
```

and another result "diskutil info -all"

```
diskutil info -all
   Device Identifier:         disk0
   Device Node:               /dev/disk0
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk0
   Device / Media Name:       APPLE SSD AP0512M

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Verified

   Disk Size:                 500.3 GB (500277792768 Bytes) (exactly 977105064 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Virtual:                   No
   Hardware AES Support:      Yes

**********

   Device Identifier:         disk0s1
   Device Node:               /dev/disk0s1
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk0

   Volume Name:               EFI
   Mounted:                   No

   Partition Type:            EFI
   File System Personality:   MS-DOS FAT32
   Type (Bundle):             msdos
   Name (User Visible):       MS-DOS (FAT32)

   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Verified
   Volume UUID:               9A60D8E2-0178-38BD-A835-EE493120E5E4
   Disk / Partition UUID:     B03A7873-6E91-42D6-95D3-B31BAB3846A6
   Partition Offset:          24576 Bytes (6 4096-Byte-Device-Blocks)

   Disk Size:                 314.6 MB (314572800 Bytes) (exactly 614400 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Volume Total Space:        0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:         0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          Not applicable (not mounted)

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Hardware AES Support:      Yes

**********

   Device Identifier:         disk0s2
   Device Node:               /dev/disk0s2
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk0

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Partition Type:            Apple_APFS
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Verified
   Disk / Partition UUID:     40407B6B-4395-49CC-8AA1-0E41683DF90B
   Partition Offset:          314597376 Bytes (76806 4096-Byte-Device-Blocks)

   Disk Size:                 120.0 GB (120000061440 Bytes) (exactly 234375120 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Hardware AES Support:      Yes

   This disk is an APFS Physical Store.  APFS Information:
   APFS Container:            disk1
   Fusion Drive:              No

**********

   Device Identifier:         disk0s3
   Device Node:               /dev/disk0s3
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk0

   Volume Name:               DAVE.DATA
   Mounted:                   Yes
   Mount Point:               /Volumes/DAVE.DATA

   Partition Type:            Microsoft Basic Data
   File System Personality:   NTFS
   Type (Bundle):             ntfs
   Name (User Visible):       Windows NT File System (NTFS)

   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Verified
   Volume UUID:               A1B6E9FC-41B9-410C-B65C-EEA795CB5841
   Disk / Partition UUID:     0000E323-FF70-F056-9635-D70146C60100
   Partition Offset:          120314658816 Bytes (29373696 4096-Byte-Device-Blocks)

   Disk Size:                 71.0 GB (70999080960 Bytes) (exactly 138670080 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Volume Total Space:        71.0 GB (70999076864 Bytes) (exactly 138670072 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Used Space:         53.5 GB (53513015296 Bytes) (exactly 104517608 512-Byte-Units) (75.4%)
   Volume Free Space:         17.5 GB (17486061568 Bytes) (exactly 34152464 512-Byte-Units) (24.6%)
   Allocation Block Size:     4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          Yes

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Hardware AES Support:      Yes

**********

   Device Identifier:         disk1
   Device Node:               /dev/disk1
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk1
   Device / Media Name:       APPLE SSD AP0512M

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       EF57347C-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Verified
   Disk / Partition UUID:     819106C4-0E83-4596-9531-E6A9117B9339

   Disk Size:                 120.0 GB (120000061440 Bytes) (exactly 234375120 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Virtual:                   Yes
   Hardware AES Support:      Yes

   This disk is an APFS Container.  APFS Information:
   APFS Physical Store:       disk0s2
   Fusion Drive:              No
**********

   Device Identifier:         disk1s1
   Device Node:               /dev/disk1s1
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk1

   Volume Name:               Macintosh HD - Data
   Mounted:                   Yes
   Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/Data

   Partition Type:            41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   File System Personality:   APFS
   Type (Bundle):             apfs
   Name (User Visible):       APFS
   Owners:                    Enabled

   OS Can Be Installed:       Yes
   Booter Disk:               disk1s2
   Recovery Disk:             disk1s3
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Verified
   Volume UUID:               BE9FF043-B60E-4F90-8A86-6E437125DAED
   Disk / Partition UUID:     BE9FF043-B60E-4F90-8A86-6E437125DAED

   Disk Size:                 120.0 GB (120000061440 Bytes) (exactly 234375120 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Container Total Space:     120.0 GB (120000061440 Bytes) (exactly 234375120 512-Byte-Units)
   Container Free Space:      16.8 GB (16807874560 Bytes) (exactly 32827880 512-Byte-Units)
   Allocation Block Size:     4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          No

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Hardware AES Support:      Yes

   This disk is an APFS Volume.  APFS Information:
   APFS Container:            disk1
   APFS Physical Store:       disk0s2
   Fusion Drive:              No
   APFS Volume Group:         BE9FF043-B60E-4F90-8A86-6E437125DAED
   FileVault:                 Yes
   Locked:                    No

**********

   Device Identifier:         disk1s2
   Device Node:               /dev/disk1s2
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk1

   Volume Name:               Preboot
   Mounted:                   No

   Partition Type:            41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   File System Personality:   APFS
   Type (Bundle):             apfs
   Name (User Visible):       APFS
   Owners:                    Disabled

   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Booter Disk:               disk1s2
   Recovery Disk:             disk1s3
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Verified
   Volume UUID:               6CE7F107-CB99-4AB1-BB45-FDE35AA394B3
   Disk / Partition UUID:     6CE7F107-CB99-4AB1-BB45-FDE35AA394B3

   Disk Size:                 120.0 GB (120000061440 Bytes) (exactly 234375120 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Container Total Space:     120.0 GB (120000061440 Bytes) (exactly 234375120 512-Byte-Units)
   Container Free Space:      16.8 GB (16807874560 Bytes) (exactly 32827880 512-Byte-Units)

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          Not applicable (not mounted)

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Hardware AES Support:      Yes

   This disk is an APFS Volume.  APFS Information:
   APFS Container:            disk1
   APFS Physical Store:       disk0s2
   Fusion Drive:              No
   FileVault:                 No
   Locked:                    No

**********

   Device Identifier:         disk1s3
   Device Node:               /dev/disk1s3
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk1

   Volume Name:               Recovery
   Mounted:                   No

   Partition Type:            41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   File System Personality:   APFS
   Type (Bundle):             apfs
   Name (User Visible):       APFS
   Owners:                    Disabled

   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Booter Disk:               disk1s2
   Recovery Disk:             disk1s3
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Verified
   Volume UUID:               9AD4CEC7-1C2D-4CBA-8A3D-A53A9368BF0B
   Disk / Partition UUID:     9AD4CEC7-1C2D-4CBA-8A3D-A53A9368BF0B

   Disk Size:                 120.0 GB (120000061440 Bytes) (exactly 234375120 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Container Total Space:     120.0 GB (120000061440 Bytes) (exactly 234375120 512-Byte-Units)
   Container Free Space:      16.8 GB (16807874560 Bytes) (exactly 32827880 512-Byte-Units)

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          Not applicable (not mounted)

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Hardware AES Support:      Yes

   This disk is an APFS Volume.  APFS Information:
   APFS Container:            disk1
   APFS Physical Store:       disk0s2
   Fusion Drive:              No
   FileVault:                 No
   Locked:                    No

**********

   Device Identifier:         disk1s4
   Device Node:               /dev/disk1s4
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk1

   Volume Name:               VM
   Mounted:                   Yes
   Mount Point:               /private/var/vm

   Partition Type:            41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   File System Personality:   APFS
   Type (Bundle):             apfs
   Name (User Visible):       APFS
   Owners:                    Enabled

   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Booter Disk:               disk1s2
   Recovery Disk:             disk1s3
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Verified
   Volume UUID:               095229EF-0BEA-4DE1-B2CB-396DC83BAF7D
   Disk / Partition UUID:     095229EF-0BEA-4DE1-B2CB-396DC83BAF7D

   Disk Size:                 120.0 GB (120000061440 Bytes) (exactly 234375120 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Container Total Space:     120.0 GB (120000061440 Bytes) (exactly 234375120 512-Byte-Units)
   Container Free Space:      16.8 GB (16807874560 Bytes) (exactly 32827880 512-Byte-Units)
   Allocation Block Size:     4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          No

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Hardware AES Support:      Yes

   This disk is an APFS Volume.  APFS Information:
   APFS Container:            disk1
   APFS Physical Store:       disk0s2
   Fusion Drive:              No
   FileVault:                 No
   Locked:                    No

**********

   Device Identifier:         disk1s5
   Device Node:               /dev/disk1s5
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk1

   Volume Name:               Macintosh HD
   Mounted:                   Yes
   Mount Point:               /

   Partition Type:            41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   File System Personality:   APFS
   Type (Bundle):             apfs
   Name (User Visible):       APFS
   Owners:                    Enabled

   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Booter Disk:               disk1s2
   Recovery Disk:             disk1s3
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Verified
   Volume UUID:               758CFE27-7CE8-4F0D-9AA0-AFC47EA96E12
   Disk / Partition UUID:     758CFE27-7CE8-4F0D-9AA0-AFC47EA96E12

   Disk Size:                 120.0 GB (120000061440 Bytes) (exactly 234375120 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Container Total Space:     120.0 GB (120000061440 Bytes) (exactly 234375120 512-Byte-Units)
   Container Free Space:      16.8 GB (16807874560 Bytes) (exactly 32827880 512-Byte-Units)
   Allocation Block Size:     4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          Yes

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Hardware AES Support:      Yes

   This disk is an APFS Volume.  APFS Information:
   APFS Container:            disk1
   APFS Physical Store:       disk0s2
   Fusion Drive:              No
   APFS Volume Group:         BE9FF043-B60E-4F90-8A86-6E437125DAED
   FileVault:                 Yes
   Locked:                    No

**********

   Device Identifier:         disk2
   Device Node:               /dev/disk2
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk2
   Device / Media Name:       Disk Image

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  Disk Image
   SMART Status:              Not Supported

   Disk Size:                 184.6 MB (184590336 Bytes) (exactly 360528 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:           Yes
   Read-Only Volume:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           External
   Removable Media:           Removable
   Media Removal:             Software-Activated

   Solid State:               Info not available
   Virtual:                   Yes

**********

   Device Identifier:         disk2s1
   Device Node:               /dev/disk2s1
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk2

   Volume Name:               CleanMyMac X
   Mounted:                   Yes
   Mount Point:               /Volumes/CleanMyMac X

   Partition Type:            Apple_HFS
   File System Personality:   HFS+
   Type (Bundle):             hfs
   Name (User Visible):       Mac OS Extended
   Owners:                    Disabled

   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  Disk Image
   SMART Status:              Not Supported
   Volume UUID:               486B3C5F-61F6-39A5-B4B7-430EB60F9537
   Disk / Partition UUID:     ADF61AC6-C653-4A22-B9C9-AE0311C81E5B
   Partition Offset:          20480 Bytes (40 512-Byte-Device-Blocks)

   Disk Size:                 184.5 MB (184549376 Bytes) (exactly 360448 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

   Volume Total Space:        184.5 MB (184549376 Bytes) (exactly 360448 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Used Space:         176.2 MB (176177152 Bytes) (exactly 344096 512-Byte-Units) (95.5%)
   Volume Free Space:         8.4 MB (8372224 Bytes) (exactly 16352 512-Byte-Units) (4.5%)
   Allocation Block Size:     4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:           Yes
   Read-Only Volume:          Yes

   Device Location:           External
   Removable Media:           Removable
   Media Removal:             Software-Activated

   Solid State:               Info not available

**********
```

Comment: Please provide information as text not images so that it can be read

Comment: Also: what do you see in Disk Utility? Was the disk used for something else before (e.g. Bootcamp/Windows)?

Comment: Edited the question with output text , with command "diskutil list"

Comment: @mmmmmm appreciate your further advise with additional information added.

Comment: @nohillside there was bootcamp partition, and i decided to remove it, windows is occupying a lots of disk space, most probably due to my development work with Node Js and React projects. I wanted to free up disk space and allow my MacOS (Catalina) to have more disk space for XCode installation.

Answer (score 2):

Bootcamp partitions require you to use Bootcamp Assistant (same tool you used to create a Bootcamp partition) to remove them and the associated Windows assets:

https://support.apple.com/guide/bootcamp-assistant/remove-windows-from-your-mac-using-boot-camp-bcmp59c41c31/mac

As Apple says *"WARNING: Do not use any other utilities to remove Windows or a partition that was created with Boot Camp."*

If for some reason this can't be made to work, there is an answer from a few years ago that may be helpful:

[Can't delete BOOTCAMP partition](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305172/cant-delete-bootcamp-partition)